# Создание коллажа с использованием WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Стоит задача, создать коллаж из нескольких изображений и сохранить его в отдельную папку, с использованием WPF. Я смог додуматься только до этого. 
Как сделать склейку всех изображений из Image[], я не понял, как и создание массива изображений с помощью Bitmap.

Хотелось бы увидеть пример кода.

```
public int Counter = 0;
public Image[] Img = new Image[25];
public BitmapImage[] Images = new BitmapImage[25];

private void LoadClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        this.Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openDialog.FileName));

        Img[Counter] = this.Image;
        Counter++;
        CountImage.Text = Convert.ToString(Counter);
    }
}

private void MakeCollag(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться `RenderTargetBitmap`:

```
private void MakeCollage(IEnumerable<string> imageFilenames, string outputFilename) {
    var collage = new Grid();
    foreach (var filename in imageFilenames) {
        collage.Children.Add(new Image {
            Source = LoadBitmapImage(filename),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        });
    }

    collage.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    collage.Arrange(new Rect(0d, 0d, collage.DesiredSize.Width, collage.DesiredSize.Height));

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)collage.DesiredSize.Width, (int)collage.DesiredSize.Height,
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(collage);

    bitmap.SaveAsPng(outputFilename);
}
```

Если нужно выстроить изображения в ряд:

```
    var collage = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    foreach (var filename in imageFilenames) {
        collage.Children.Add(new Image {
            Source = LoadBitmapImage(filename),
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Margin = new Thickness(4, 0, 0, 0)
        });
    }
```

Вообще, это же обычные контролы, можно расставить всё как угодно. На всякий случай, моя версия `LoadBitmapImage()`:

```
private static BitmapImage LoadBitmapImage(string filename) {
    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(filename);
    bi.EndInit();
    bi.Freeze();
    return bi;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: СПАСИБО, спасибо за `bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;`! Я чуть с ума не сошел, пока искал почему моя гадская программа не обновляет картинку. Даже не мог догадаться что этот клятый `BitmapImage` имеет кучу кешей. И еще раз, спасибо.

Comment: @Илья, рад, что помогло. Если вдруг понадобится, к слову, выводить много картинок с диска, могу скинуть код самодельного контрола — грузит асинхронно, безо всяких конвертеров, с небольшим кешем (с учётом даты изменения файла) и всё такое.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один метод с `RenderTargetBitmap`, не использующий `Grid` и layout manager:

```
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    int imageNumber = 0;
    int gap = 5; // расстояние между картинками
    foreach (var image in images)
    {
        int x = imageNumber % numberOfColumns, y = imageNumber / numberOfColumns;
        drawingContext.DrawImage(
            image,
            new System.Windows.Rect(
                (pixelWidth + gap) * x,
                (pixelHeight + gap) * y,
                pixelWidth,
                pixelHeight));
        i++;
    }
}

var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (pixelWidth + gap) * numberOfColumns - gap,
    (pixelHeight + gap) * numberOfRows - gap,
    96,
    96,
    PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
```