# Как поместить картинку на форму без сохранения на диск. (использую Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Сейчас у меня в `MainView.xaml`

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Path=map.MapImage}"></Image>
```

А в `MapViewModel.cs`

```
public BitmapImage MapImage
    {
        get { return Map.MapComb; }
        set
        {
            Map.MapComb = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MapImage");
        }
    }
```

Код работает как надо (но мне так не надо), я могу любой файлик с изображением запихнуть в MapImage и он отобразится на форме.

А нужно в `MapViewModel.cs`

```
public Image MapImage //System.Drawing.Image
    {
        get { return Map.MapComb; }
        set
        {
            Map.MapComb = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MapImage");
        }
    }
```

Что должно быть в `MainView.xaml`? Принимается вариант с правками в `MapViewModel.cs` и где угодно. ГЛАВНОЕ рисовать на форме картинку из переменной, не сохраняя её никуда на диск.

PS: стараюсь сделать `MVVM` приложение.

Comment: Еще. Если у вас карта, как я понял, посмотрите на проект https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/ . У них есть класс TileLayer, посмотрите реализацию.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov очень хотелось бы познакомиться с этим решением. Но мне не удалось найти код. Или описание принципа, на котором построен XAML Map Control. Ткните пальцем, если можно.

Comment: Код там разбросан. Конкретно [про загрузку тайлов](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MapControl/TileImageLoader.WPF.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство `Source`. 
Например, в коде View можно сделать так:

```
Children.Add(new Image
{
     Source = bmp
});
```

где `bmp` типа `ImageSource`. Можно его создать из массива байт. Например:

```
byte[] array;
....
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
var ms = new MemoryStream(array);
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.StreamSource = ms;
bmp.EndInit();
```

Comment: Мне помогла строка `var ms = new MemoryStream(array);`. Натолкнула на мысль. Как получилось напишу в вопросе. Но появился новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

С `System.Drawing.Image` не подойдёт, т. к. WPF работает лишь с классами наподобие `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`. Можно написать конвертер, который будет превращать `System.Drawing.Image` в `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`, но это скорее всего не нужно. Вы должны в том месте, где вы *получаете* вашу картинку, получать её сразу в правильном формате.

Comment: Собственно, чего и ожидал - что будет непонятно чего я хочу. Поясню: картинки качаются из интернета и собираются в одну, а потом отображаются (это карта). И разумеется можно переходить в разные точки карты. Думал оформить `<Image Source="{Binding Path=map.MapImage}"></Image>`. Но в таком случае надо создавать ровно столько картинок, сколько раз пролистал карту (если не кэширую BitmapImage, то меняя получаю исключение, если кэширую, то картинка не меняется).

Comment: @Илья: Ну хорошо, картинки вы скачали, а откуда у вас `System.Drawing.Image`?

Comment: @Илья: Фразу «если не кэширую BitmapImage, то меняя получаю исключение, если кэширую, то картинка не меняется» я не понял. Исключение указывает, что вы где-то допустили ошибку, а не что кешировать нельзя.

Comment: @Илья: И у вас в вопросе сказано «не сохраняя на диск». Причём тут сохранение на диск? ImageSource можно получить и без сохранения.

Comment: С помощью `System.Drawing.Image` объединяю [несколько картинок в одну](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598579/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-jpeg-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0). Насчет кэширования я немного некорректно объяснил. Кеширование работает правильно, но когда я пересохраняю файл из которого создал `BitmapImage` - вылазят бока.  В ответ на третий вопрос: пока сохраняю на диск, но хочу от этого избавиться.

Comment: @Илья: Ну так вы объединяйте при помощи BitmapImage, а о System.Drawing.Image забудьте. Вы ж сами себе создаёте проблемы.

Comment: ну с `Image` я могу сделать `Image img = new Bitmap(1024,1024)` А как быть в случае с `BitmapImage`?

Comment: @Илья: Гляньте сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584555/10105

Comment: взял я ваш код по ссылке и склеил части в `BitmapImage`. Но так и не смог разобраться с политикой кеширования. Но получилось сконвертировать `Image` в `BitmapImage`.